# Scrape Text from Mega.nz Archive (Python)

Tags: python, web-scraping

I recently ran into an issue that I'm not sure what to do about.  I have the links to *a lot* of Mega.nz archives that I need to scrape the text contents of (the text that is displayed on the page), but I'm not sure how to do it.  For example, see this archive:
[image]

Clearly it has lots of text on it (specifically the folder names) that I need to be obtain (blurred for privacy reasons).  However, when I view the source of the page, I get this:

[image]

And none of the links on that page lead to any of the text information either!  What I would normally do is just use Python to download the source HTML and then analyze that, but clearly that won't work in this situation.  I can use Control + F in google chrome to search the text of each archive manually, but I have hundreds of these archives that I need to obtain the text from, so that method clearly won't work either.

I'm not really sure what I can do in this situation.  Is there any way that I can get this text?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What library are you using? I'm pretty sure you are using `requests` or `scrapy`.

You better use Selenium for that kind of websites,

To be brief, selenium let you control a web browser via Python. The main feature is the Javascript within the DOM is computed and executed, so you access to the "real computed" HTML source.

What I would do,

```
driver = selenium.webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('http://www.mega.nz/egg/bacon/SPAM')
time.sleep(3)
raw_html = driver.page_source
```

It basically call the URL, wait 3 seconds to be sure everything is loaded and Javascript is executed, then get the **current** page source.

After that, you just need to parse `raw_html` into a `bs4.BeautifulSoup` instance and extract data.

---

Ho and since you seems to compute this list only one time, you could just hit `F12` key on your browser, find `console` tab and push some Javascript to extract the list :)